# Jupyter Book build fails after default create

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-sphinx, jupyter-lab

I'm still learning how this all works, so please bear with me.

I'm running conda 4.8.5 on my Windows 10 machine. I've already installed all necessary Jupyter extensions, I think (Jupyter Lab, Jupyter Notebook, Jupyter Book, Node.js, and their dependencies).

The problem might have to do with the fact that I've installed Miniconda on a separate (D:/) drive.

I've set up a virtual environment (MyEnv) with all the packages I might need for this project. These are the steps I follow:

- Launch CMD window
- `$ conda activate MyEnv`
- `$ jupyter-lab --notebook-dir "Documents/Jupyter Books"`
- At this point a browser tab opens running Jupyter Lab
- From the launcher within Jupyter Lab, open a terminal
- `$ cd "Documents/Jupyter Books"`
- `$ jb create MyCoolBook`
- New folder with template book contents gets created in this directory (Yay!)
- Without editing anything: `$ jb build MyCoolBook`
- A folder gets added to *MyCoolBook* called _build, but it doesn't contain much more than a few CSS files.
- The terminal throws [this](https://pastebin.com/ygiWA7QW) error traceback which wasn't very helpful to me. The issue may be obvious to an experienced user.

I am not sure how to proceed. I've reset the entire environment a few times trying to get this to work. What do you suggest? I'm considering submitting a bug report but I want to rule out the very reasonable possibility that I'm being silly.

Comment: Please include the traceback in the body of your question. External links tend to break, which nukes a lot of value for future visitors to this question.

Comment: I don't yet have the rep to edit my post (I was only allowed a quick edit to remove a wrong tag). If you could make the edit I can try to approve it ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked around in the Github page/forum for Jupyter Book. Turns out it's a matter of text encoding in Windows (I could have avoided this by reading deep into the documentation).

If anyone runs across this issue just know that it can be fixed by reverting to some release, Python 3.7.*, and setting an environment variable (`PYTHONUTF8=1`) but this is not something I would recommend because some other packages might require the default system encoding. Instead, follow the instructions in this section of [the documentation](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/advanced/windows.html).

Comment: link to documentation is broken.